# error when using formData jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am uploading an image using a form. For that I have to use `formData`. My code is returning an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Here is my code:

```
var url = ajaxurl,
    formData = new FormData(),
    _this = this,
    form = $(this.$avatarForm[0]),
    avatar_src = form.find('.avatar_src').val(),
    avatar_data = form.find('.avatar_data').val(),
    action = form.find('.action').val();
    formData.append("avatar_src", avatar_src);
    formData.append("avatar_data", avatar_data);
    formData.append("action", action);
    console.log(formData);

$.ajax(url, {
    type: 'post',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        _this.submitDone(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Which line of your code is causing that error? Does execution reach the `console.log()`? Is the AJAX request being sent at all?

Comment: `form = $(this.$avatarForm[0]),` what is `this` here? and you have syntax errors buddy.......:)

Comment: @Jai form is the form selector

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan error shown on this line $.ajax(url, {

Comment: @muhammadumarfarooqfrank this is very simple go through the documentation you can find this `$.ajax({url  ...etc...})`

Comment: @Jai that is fine. i am using prototype. i hope u  understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: 'post',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        _this.submitDone(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: can you try after remove dataType?

Comment: sorry you can put dataType as it is, also put this  "processData: false,", now i think its work

Comment: if this answer is helpful to you, so can you accept my answer??

Comment: update your answer with processData: false, i will accept it.